# image doesn't change size if the window size was adjusted, openCV3.4.1_5 C++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I'm new to openCV and I'm using 3.4.1_5, C++ in Xcode on Mac. I used Homebrew to install opencv. 
I'm following an openCV tutorial which is conducted in VS on Windows. Here's a link to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WHrr_5xO3Q&list=PLAp0ZhYvW6XbEveYeefGSuLhaPlFML9gP&index=3).

Basically, the tutorial shows how to create/resize a window, which is easy. So I have some code like this which is basically the same as in the tutorial:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
....
namedWindow("modi", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
imshow("modi", modi);
resizeWindow("modi", modi.cols/2, modi.rows/2); //modi is a Mat
....
```

Supposedly, the image will be the same except it will be 1/4 of the original size and fit into the resized window. This is the case in the tutorial. However, it's not the case on my mac. My image stays the same size, and only the window shrinks to 1/4. If I drag the border of the window, the "covered" part of the image is revealed.

This actually poses a problem to my project later on, so I want to figure out why. I want to achieve what the tutorial achieves, and I've tried all window parameter, like AUTOSIZE, KEEPRATIO, OPENGL, etc. None of them worked. I'm thinking about if it's due to platform or version problem, but I have no way to test them.

Please help! Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: OpenCV does not resize the image to fit the window, since the GUI elements are incredibly basic, you need to do it yourself. You can use [cv::resize](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) to the cv::Mat directly and then display it

Comment: Thanks @api55. But that's done in the tutorial, the image is able to match the size of the window however the window's size is adjusted. Is there any way I can achieve that without my code?

Comment: hmmm, a lot of people in that tutorial had problems resizing... could be that it works in certain language/system... however, you had the wrong order, the imshow goes first in the tutorial and then resizewindow

Comment: oops, yeah you are right, I messed up when pasting the code here. The code was in the same order in my file, just pasted in the wrong order here. I will update the question. Thanks